# Magento 2 set locale in CLI command module

Tags: magento2, cli, locale

I'm developing a command line module in magento 2 and I cannot find a way to set locale programmatically.

The module takes care of creating a pdf invoice from an order and sends it via email to customer. All is going fine but the mail and the pdf invoice are in english.

Also if I try to print something like `echo __('my phrase')`, and I have the corresponding translation in `/i18n/it_IT.csv` file, it doesn't print the translated sentence.

I'm stuck there since 8h or so, trying a bunch of ways to do that.

If I instantiate a local resolver instance (`Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface`) via `objectManager` or injecting it in the constructor and then try `$this->_localResolver->getLocale()`, it prints `it_IT`, but nothing happens.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
$locale = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface');
echo $locale->getLocale();  //it prints 'it_IT'
$locale->setLocale('it_IT');
$locale->setDefaultLocale('it_IT');

echo __('Price including VAT') . "\n\r"; //It prints 'Price including VAT' and not the translated sentence.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok following Raphael suggestions I found how to set locale and enable traslations in a command CLI module:

```
    /** @var Magento\Framework\TranslateInterface */
    $localeInterface = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\TranslateInterface');
    $localeInterface->loadData();
    // Inizializing \Magento\Framework\Phrase 
    \Magento\Framework\Phrase::setRenderer($this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\Phrase\RendererInterface'));
```

Hope this could be usefull to someone else.

Comment: i try this solution but its not working on my end could you pls describe me in detail i need to set locale programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure setting the locale of `Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface` is not enough as this is only for the locale resolver.

I reckon you also need to to set the locale interface locale by calling:

```
$localeInterface = $objectManager->create('Magento\Framework\TranslateInterface');
$localeInterface->setLocale('it_IT');
```

NB: [do not use the object manager directly](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/117098/2380), the code above is just an example on how to do it.

If this still does not work I suggest you check this thread in details to start debugging your problem: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/106294/2380

Comment: Hi Raphael, it doesn't work :(

Comment: @floyd see my updated answer to help you debug your issue

Answer (score 0):

I build a Translation Helper as Example for Magento2.

You can find here:

https://gist.github.com/larsroettig/45af9c1746bbb61c273067136c06700d