# Magento 2 : How to do translation text as per area and scope vise

Tags: magento2, inline-translations

I read this answer [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/104732/how-does-translation-scope-work-in-magento-2).

**Extension example :** [click here](https://marketplace.magento.com/shayacrich-wheelbarrow-translator.html)

It's perfect extension as I want. But, I need in M2.

But, I want to do translate like :

- If "Test" string comes from **Abc_Test** Module. Then, translate only
  working in Abc_Test module text.
- If "Test" string also available in **Magento_Catalog** Module. Then,
  translate text apply which assign in Magento_Catalog Module.
- If "Test" string also available in **Magento_Catalog** Module and set
  Area **Frontend**. Then, translate text apply only in frontend side
  which assign in Magento_Catalog Module.

How it works ?

Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient solution for your requirement is by [Generating a translation dictionary](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict) and from the generated translation dictionary you can create your own language packages.

The advantage of using a generated translation dictionary is that you will have a dictionary file with a collected list of all existing phrases and words according to the module(not sure about the area scope but it lists all the translatable words and phrases).

Comment: Is it possible to create as per area and scope wise?

Comment: If around 80+ module in project then how to manage dictionary file and on which location?

Comment: the translation dictionary file is a single .csv file of translatable words and phrases. you can directly find and replace each word you want to translate

Comment: you can check sample https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269056/translation-file-magento-2-i18n?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: store wise Yes but im not sure with scope.

Comment: Let me check that.